# No route matches - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Setting up my second project in Rails (first not following a tutorial) and have run into a problem I can't solve with my routes. Everything works as I'd like it to with my routes.rb file like:

```
AnimalApp::Application.routes.draw do

    root to: 'static_pages#index'
        # resources :animal
    match '/help', to: 'static_pages#help'
    match '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'
    match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
    match '/league', to: 'static_pages#league'
    match '/animal', to: 'animal#new'
```

Except I can't access my animals! Going to /animal/1 throws an error : 
`No route matches [GET] "/animal/1"`

To fix this I changed my routes as follows:

```
    AnimalApp::Application.routes.draw do

    root to: 'static_pages#index'
        resources :animal
    match '/help', to: 'static_pages#help'
    match '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'
    match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
    match '/league', to: 'static_pages#league'
    #match '/animal', to: 'animal#new'
```

However, when I try and view any of the other pages on my site I get the following error: 
`No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"animal"}`

For more information see below my controllers:
(static pages)

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def help
  end

  def league
  end

  def contact
  end

  def about
  end

  def index
  end

  def show
  end
end
```

animals controller

```
class AnimalController < ApplicationController
    def new
    @animal = Animal.new
    end

def show
    @animal = Animal.new
end
end
```

And, also, I've run `rake routes` I get:

```
animal_index GET    /animal(.:format)          animal#index
            POST    /animal(.:format)          animal#create
  new_animal GET    /animal/new(.:format)      animal#new
 edit_animal GET    /animal/:id/edit(.:format) animal#edit
      animal GET    /animal/:id(.:format)      animal#show
             PUT    /animal/:id(.:format)      animal#update
          DELETE    /animal/:id(.:format)      animal#destroy
            root    /                          static_pages#index
            help    /help(.:format)            static_pages#help
           about    /about(.:format)           static_pages#about
         contact    /contact(.:format)         static_pages#contact
          league    /league(.:format)          static_pages#league
                    /animal(.:format)          animal#new
```

Does anybody have any idea how I can get my site back and also allow myself to see objects in my animal database under the URI /animal/[:id]?

Answer (score 5):

Make it `resources :animals` instead of `resources :animal`

`rake routes` should show the following output:

```
    animals GET    /animals(.:format)          animals#index
            POST   /animals(.:format)          animals#create
 new_animal GET    /animals/new(.:format)      animals#new
edit_animal GET    /animals/:id/edit(.:format) animals#edit
     animal GET    /animals/:id(.:format)      animals#show
            PUT    /animals/:id(.:format)      animals#update
            DELETE /animals/:id(.:format)      animals#destroy
```

Comment: Hi,

Have made the changes you suggested and it has made my routes (or at least the 'animals' ones) appear as above, I still can't see the page. Same error as before when looking at any of the other pages (`localhost:3000/` as the primary example) but now the error `uninitialized constant AnimalsController` when visiting `/animals/1`.

Comment: In the animals controller file, change the name of the controller from `AnimalController` to 'AnimalsController`.

Comment: Also, I strongly recommend going through the first few chapters of [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) in detail so that you get a solid understanding of the Rails Architecture, along with the naming conventions.

Comment: Even doing that (the renaming of the animal controller) I'm still not getting anything on any of the other pages on the site. I've reread the tutorial time and time again (that was the first app and I've been following it as closely as possible with this app). I'll keep on reading!